# Context.SubmitChanges vs TransactionScope.Submit memory consumption

Tags: c#, dbcontext, transactionscope

What i would like to know about these two methods is how they work with memory and which approach is better in my situation.

Now i need to regenerate tables (about 1,5 GB per table), my first solution is to consume the new data from a source ( a webservice in my scenario) , so i open new context to db, delete old tables (in the context) , i put the new data in the context, submit the changes to the context (so changes became effective only if there are no errors).

What i have seen is that proceeding in that way memory consumption became a issue, it seems like the data remain in memory until i commit the changes (using the created contex).

So my idea is to use chunks (and every chunck operate with few data using the same logic described above), but i need to rollback if any of the chunk used fails its operation, so i assume i need a TransactionScope. What i would like to know now is if the TransactionScope works in memory till the commit like the context or if use some logging tecnique so that it can rollback every step (but every step does not remain into memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data remains in-memory because entities are attached to their context. L2S does not support detaching entities so that's not a working strategy.

Better solution: Consider opening one database connection, one TransactionScope and creating a L2S context *per batch*. You can give the context constructor an existing connection. That way memory usage is constant and you can use a transaction.

Comment: i am not sure to have correctly understood your answer. Actually i use a LinqToSql datacontext and i commit all the data at the end (any exception stop the flow so end is not reached if there are any trouble).
Proceeding in that way i see that too much memory is used, so i have thought to use chunks.
Every chunks work like described above, so it open new datacontext (using linq to sql) and then commit their changes (and be finalized i supposed).
The only difference is that a transaction scope is added and committed only at the end.
Is that what you mean with "creating an EF context per batch"?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You seem to have the chunking approach implemented but with multiple db connections. That causes distributed transactions to be activated. Distributed trans are not the right thing 99% of the time. Share one db connection.

Comment: ah sorry i have miss something in my translation, i have only one db, every chunk simply instantiate a new dbdatacontext (L2S context) with the same connection string, do insertion and then commit.
So there will be one big deletion at start (inside a transaction) a lot of little insertion (as much as chunks are) with subsequent commit, and at the end if everything gone right a transaction scope commit.
If is that what you mean now i have understand.
Thanks again and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Context != connection. You should reuse the connection for all contexts. Else you are going to involve MSDTC which is the devil in disguise.

Comment: In my understanding the "connection" is the ConnectionString, and context is the DBDataContext used for a specific (and atomic as possible) operation  on db (each operatoin open a db connection and the is closed), using that ConnectionString that is persistent usually a constant in the configuration file.
Finally MSDTC is used only if DB is remote, but if both program and DB reside on the same machine there is no need to enable MSDTC.
Let me know if i made any mistakes, i am not an expert, so may be i have made some wrong assumptions.

Comment: That's mostly false. Look at DataContext.Connection to see what I mean. MSDTC is activated when multiple connections are opened. Doesn't matter where the databases are.

Comment: thanks i have finally released an update with improvements that you have suggest and works like a charm.